# Reference request: harmonic analysis with non-Lebesgue reference measure

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

The Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$
admits the following polar decomposition:
$$
L(dx) = r^{d-1} dr \lambda(dy),
$$
where  is the uniform measure on the Euclidean unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and where $x=ry$.
Now, change the uniform measure on the Euclidean unit sphere by another positive finite measure (non-degenerate) on the Euclidean unit sphere. Namely,
$$
L'(dx) = r^{d-1}dr\sigma(dy).
$$
where $\sigma$ is a positive finite measure (non-degenerate) on the Euclidean unit sphere $\mathbb{R}^d$ and where $x=ry$. Where can I find harmonic analysis results based on this new reference measure ?

Comment: If you assume that new neasure $L'$ (or $\sigma$) is doubling, you can use harmonic analysis on homogenuous spaces. But I do not know if this is the case of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. Indeed, the doubling condition came up at some point. I am interested in Hölderian type regularity result.